# Force image link download

Tags: 7, media

I have an image path like `http://example.com/sites/default/files/image.jpg`.

I have a download link like:

`<a href="http://example.com/sites/default/files/image.jpg">Download</a`>

So on clicking on the download it opens the image in the browser. Instead I want when I click on the Download link, it should download that image.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you looking to do this in content or theme markup? I ask because this seems like a question that might be a general HTML question (off topic), but could possible be Drupal as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DownloadFile](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file) module. This module provides display formatter, for images, file etc, that uses downloadable links(of type: */download/file/fid/[fid]*) and should be compatible with older browsers.

Note:

- If you are doing custom coding, you can use file id (fid) to create your download link.
- You must upload the image, so that it can be assigned a file id.

[image]

Comment: its not a cck field. I have the image url and I want to download the image from that url programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers it works:

```
<a download="image.jpg" href="http://example.com/sites/default/files/image.jpg">Download</a>
```

Comment: I believe it answers the question, though it should be mentioned the download attribute has [mixed support and doesn't work for Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=download). And this isn't a Drupal-centric answer.